# Using PHP/HTML link to run an SQL query without jQuery?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a project in school and I'm trying to use php and sql to create a web front end with a database back end. I have tried to research this thoroughly, but I have had no success. I am trying to click on a link and run an SQL query based on the ID of the link that was clicked.

Code is pastebin'd below:
https://pastebin.com/sH6DXtQU
I believe it is something to do with;

```
$_Post or $_Get
```

So essentially I'm trying to click on one of the actors names ad it display all the films they have been in, as you can see at the bottom of the page i have made a very basic attempt at showing the films using actorID form (1-6). If possible without any jQuery but if it is necessary i will use it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Include your code _in the question_, not off-site

Comment: First of all, all code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just on an external site - so please edit accordingly. Secondly, what ID? None of the links you are generating there does have any id or URL parameters, they are all just `<a href="#">`

Comment: I see that you are a very new user. New users are very important to us and we'd like to help you be more successful on this site. Please take a look at this [Help Article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking a good question that's likely to get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to refresh the page you need an XHR request, AJAX request in Jquery. If you don't want to use Jquery it's fine , there is a way to do it in vanilla Javascript but it's way harder to understand.

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org/', false); 
req.send(null);

if (req.status === 200) {
    console.log("Received: %s", req.responseText);
} else {
    console.log("Error: %d (%s)", req.status, req.statusText);
}
```

for a GET request. I suggest you look at the mozilla website for more documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

So your having a anchor link like the following, on click of that you want all the data of the films they have acted

### View Page

```
<!-- I am assuming that your having $row as actor details, so below you store the actor id in a attribute data-actorid and once the user clicks on the link make sure you call the event ONCLICK -->

<a class="actor_movies" href="#" data-actorid = <?php echo $row['actorid']; ?>>
    <?php echo $row['actor_name']; ?>
</a> 

/* I am assuming you have jQuery running. As the code I am writing needs jQuery Library */
<script type="javascript">
    $(.actor_movies).on('click', function(){
        actor_id = $(this).attr('data-actorid');
        $.ajax({
            'url'       : 'actor_movies.php'
            'type'      : 'POST',
            'dataType'  : 'JSON',
            'data'      : {actor_id:actor_id},
            success     : function(retObj){
                /* retObj will have the json encoded code which you can loop and do whatever you want here */
                $.each();/* Even you can use for loop as per your convenience. */
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### actor_movies.php

```
/* Include your db connection file */
include_once 'db_connect.php';

/* Check if the connection type is of POST */
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    /* filter_input get your input from specified HTTP request and even you can add filter validation and other things to it */
    $actor_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'actor_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    $actor_movies_query = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM movies WHER actor_id = '.$actor_id);

    $actor_movies = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($actor_movies_query) > 0){
        while($actor_movie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($actor_movies_query)){
            $actor_movies[] = $actor_movie;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode(['actor_movies' => $actor_movies]);
}
```